# How I know how much time I spent on distracting website in my mobile?

Tags: browser, smartphone, android-internet

I also try extension in my browser but it does not work.

I am using Kiwi browser. It's much similar to Chrome browser with some additional features one of is using extension. I'm trying almost every extension to know my web time spent on each website but it does not work.

I am also use Firefox browser but web time tracker didn't work.

Please note that I am talking about browser in my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'timeyourweb' chrome extension. At a glance, it gives you the time spent on tabs. Check it out here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timeyourweb-time-tracker/kfmlkgchpffnaphmlmjnimonlldbcpnh?hl=de&gl=US

Comment: If that did not work, these are the only other extensions i beleive will work.

Comment: If that did not work, these are the only other extensions i beleive will work.
Mind your time :  [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/mind-the-time/?src=search

Surf clock : [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/surf-clock/?src=search] @HalffunctionNobot

Comment: You also see this image https://anonfiles.com/V5y9B8sboe/Screenshot_2020-04-23-20-24-59-727_org.mozilla.firefox_jpg browser reacting that they did not record anything.

Comment: surf the web for a while and lets see if it record anything. @HalffunctionNobot